# How to delete photos from iPhoto album (not only removed from album)?

Tags: photos.app

In iPhoto, select some photos in an album, delete them only remove the photos from the albums (but are not actually deleted).

How can I delete photos (move to Trash) inside iPhoto albums (like deleting photos in Library > Photos view)?

Comment: Is your question about "How to remove a photo from the whole iPhoto library"?

Comment: I don't understand why people don't understand the question.

He's got, say, 10 photos in his library.

he's got one album with three photos.

he wants to delete the photos from the one album, and when he's done, have 7 photos left in his library.

A one step delete-from-library-when-delete-from-album thing.

Answer (score 15):

Select photos in an album, press <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work any more.

Comment: Worked like a charm. (M1 Macbook Air, Big Sur 11.6.3)

Answer (score 2):

just right click click the trash icon and go to the column menu`s trash (the vertical menu left to your screen) and click on the top right empty trash.
hope this helps.

[image: Trash]

Answer (score 1):

Easy.  When you open up your album, do a right mouse click on the image and the `Trash` icon appears. Just click that and the actual image is removed from the album but placed in the `Trash` as well.

[image]

Comment: No. At least, it does not work for me. The photo is removed from the Album but not in Trash. iPhoto 9.5.1

Comment: @JakeGould: could you clarify what is the exact function of this `Trash` button. On my iPhoto interface, this button looks like inactived (it is grey).

Answer (score 0):

There's a trash can within iPhoto. To clear the space from your hard drive, you have to empty the trash can within the program. Click "iPhoto" next to the apple when the interface is selected. It's like the 4th option down. Then your hard drive will be restored.